# Change size of vector in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, icon

I use Illustrator for changing colours and adding the svg vectors (basically icons from flaticons) to photoshop to create high fidelity mockups.

my question is, is there any way to change the width(thickness) of the svg ?
[image: see the arrows]

if you see the arrows drawn, that is what i want to achieve, and if you see on top the stroke is 0 while its complete fill.
is this even possible ?

Comment: related question http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42839/can-i-make-an-outlined-path-thicker-in-illustrator/ @Cai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your path, go to *Object → Path → Offset Path...* and select an offset.

The Offset Path command will duplicate your path, leaving you with your new path *and* the original so you should delete the original once you're done.

[image: Offset Path]