# How can I make an outlined path thinner in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I have been given some SVG icons which are all outlined paths. I need to make the strokes thinner to be consistent with the rest of a design I'm working on. Is there a way to do this without reconstructing the icons from scratch?

(What I am asking to do is [the opposite of this question.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42839/can-i-make-an-outlined-path-thicker-in-illustrator))

Comment: Just do what that question does and use a negative value instead

Comment: If you read the answer to the question linked you would know that the opposite operation of making the stroke thicker is the same operation.

Comment: @manly except offseting inwards does shorten the stroke.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CS6 screen shots.. but it's the same for newer versions as well.

Also by "outlined paths" I'm assuming you mean you have actual **shapes with fills**, not strokes with an "outline" effect applied to them.

Assume the black is your shape.... These are two separate shapes. You can do this with any number of objects at the same time....

[image]

Add a new stroke.

(Any *different* stroke color works, but an **uncommon color to the rest of the piece** will make things easier later).

[image]

Set the stroke to align "Inside" by clicking the button on the **Stroke Panel**. And configure the stroke to the weight you wish to *remove* from the shape(s).

[image]

Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu....

[image]

Click the `Merge` button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

[image]

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) to click one of these new color areas.... and choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` from the menu. The new color areas should all highlight.

(**This is where using an *uncommon* color helps.** If you used a common color, or a color which exists elsewhere in the artwork, you'll need to *manually* select all these new stroke shapes. You can't use "select same" if the color needs to remain elsewhere in the art.)

[image]

Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key....

[image]

Original again for comparison...

[image]

Using Path > Offset *can work*. It just really is dependent upon the artwork itself. Using the Object Menu item, you would duplicate the shapes. Making the removal of originals necessary. Using the effect *can* cause path intersection issues with some artwork. You'd just have to try it and see.

[image]

I detailed the stroke, then remove method because it tends to circumvent both these problems.

Comment: wouldnt using offset be simpler?

Comment: @joojaa it kind of depends... I updated my answer.

Comment: What do you mean may not align with fill. The effect changes to object but because its live it gets updated to the real data. And it gets expanded if you export the file, so no need to explicitly expand stuff.

Comment: See the screenshot above from AICC2017... that path is *not* aligned with the fill. It's an easy thing for an experienced user to overcome... not so easy if you're new to AI.

Comment: Ermh, no the path you edit is nolonger the path that is in your scene. Thats kindof point of live edits.

Comment: Joojaa.. just try it. I'm honestly *not* randomly making stuff up. If the effect is applied to the *fill* in the Appearance panel, then it may be okay (barring path intersection issues). But if it's just allied to the object, there may be a visual discrepancy.

Comment: Yes offcourse, but the path does not misalign with the fill. the fill IS the new path. The effect is just live allowing you to stack nondestructive edits on it. Like a effect layer in photoshop.

Comment: Um... -- "path does not misalign with the fill" -- did you try it? Just select an object and apply the offset effect... see image above. I didn't "engineer" that to be incorrect.

Comment: Yes yes, i know what your saying im just saying that your misinterpretting the thing. Just because your editable path does not coincide by the fill does not mean that the scene is that editable path. Even without expanding the results are what you see on screen, you just have more history to leverage. If you save that out as a eps, PDF without illustrator editing capabilities or SVG then the history will be gone. So what you see on screen is what is what you see in selection is the top of your history. But that blttom of history is the real deal.

Comment: Yes, but working *within Illustrator* that visual discrepancy can be quite a hurdle for some. I never meant that it was a production issue.... it's more an experience issue and highly dependent upon the user. And like I posted, easily overcome via Expand Appearance (or by applying the effect to the fill alone). However, path intersection issues with the effect *are* also real, even if rare. The stroke method never has any path intersection issues, that's all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49805/discussion-between-joojaa-and-scott).