# Individual shapes, turn into one shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

This is really frustrating me, as it seems it should be so simple.

I was sent a PDF map, and I want to turn what they used as individual shapes, INTO one shape that I can fill.

Even if I could just convert this group into a line with a stroke I could do it, but I am running out of ideas.

[image: Path]

The shape above, each of those squares are indivudual shapes. But what I need to do is fill that area inside them.

Any ideas?

I have tried turning it into a compound shape, I have tried live paint (even though I knew that wouldnt work because of the gaps).

Comment: If each of these black quads is actually a simple line segment with line thickness, and the underlying data can be accessed, it is a simple matter to create a shape from those segments. Can you output the line segment data? Actually, I'm betting it's already a closed shape, with a dotted line style. More information needed.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to add an outline to all the singular shapes, thick enough to fill the gaps. Then use "Expand Appearance" on all objects. Select all and use "Unite" in the pathfinder Tool window. The objects should now form a single shape which you can work with.

Comment: This would certainly work. I was a bit stuck on the idea of maintaining an accurate line along either the current outer or inner edge, or the mid-line, but it really is a question of requisite accuracy.

Comment: Come to think of it, I would add to this answer:
Break Apart, Select All, Expand Appearance, Unite, Smooth, Shrink
That should end up being close to the original shape.

Comment: Good answer! Would be perfect with some screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

This **might** work for you... It's a bit hodgepodge but gets to one shape...

This assumes each "dash" is an individual shape, no groups and no compound paths.

- Select all (I then hid the edges in the animation - `View > Hide Edges` - for better visibility)
- `Object > Transform > Transform Each`
- Increase the horizontal and vertical scale so that the gaps fill
- **Pathfinder Panel** > Merge Button
- Then possibly `Object > Path > Simplify` to remove some of the extra anchors

[image]

Then, if necessary you can deal with the thickness of the shape, since this will result in a *slightly* thicker shape in most instances: [See Here.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81390/how-can-i-make-an-outlined-path-thinner-in-illustrator)

Comment: What about instead of the scale. Youd use shape builder with sufficiently high gap detection. Should be slightly less prone to problems in a bigger shape range with no thickening. Nice trick though.

Comment: That might work Joojaa.. would require a lot more clicking. `:)`

Comment: Not beween the shapes. But on the inner area should be one click

Comment: hmm.. yeah.. maybe. I've never really tried to gap-fill via shape builder. Most of the time I simply draw new shapes separately or to fill/cover gaps, then merge/unite. i.e. in this case, I'd simply draw a new path if it were my project.

Answer (score -1):

1. > > First of all select all layer ..

Select Object > Compound path...

---

2. > > Select all layer..

Right click and compound path..

Comment: A compound path *does not* "fill in the gaps".